# Rendering only 10 search results when there are at least 20? Using Google Places API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Issue I'm having is that I am performing a Google Places radar search that returns at least 20 results. In my code, I am limiting the number of the search results to 20. So there should be a max of 20 markers on my embedded google map (this part works) and the associated list of 20 places on my results panel (this doesn't work). However, I am constantly getting only 10 results on my results panel. Here is my code performing the radar search and the addResult function in the callback (since its asynchronous):

```
function getPlaces(placeQuery, locInput){
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(locInput.geometry.location.lat(), locInput.geometry.location.lng());
    var queryValue = placeQuery.value;
    var resultsLength;

    var request = {
        location: location,
        radius: 3200,
        keyword: queryValue         
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.radarSearch(request, function callback(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            clearMarkers();
            if(results.length < 20){
                resultsLength = results.length;
            }
            else{
                resultsLength = 20;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < resultsLength; i++){

                var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0)+ i);
                var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[i].geometry.location,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon: markerIcon
                });
                markers[i].placeResult = results[i];

                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', showInfoWindow);
                setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);

                addResult(results[i], i);                   
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my addResult function:

```
function addResult(place, i) {
    var name;
    var address;

    var results = document.getElementById("results");

    service.getDetails({placeId: place.place_id}, function(result, status) {
          if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            return;
          }
          results.innerHTML += '<li>' + result.name + '</li>';
    });
}
```

I did some debug testing and the for-loop is executing completely. However in the service.getDetails in the addResult function, only 10 place IDs are going through. Not sure why... Note: Can't use jQuery or promise libraries etc.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a quota/rate limit on calls to the `.getDetails` request.  You are silently failing if the result is not "OK", add error handling and you will see the issue.

```
function addResult(place, i) {
    var name;
    var address;

    var results = document.getElementById("results");

    service.getDetails({placeId: place.place_id}, function(result, status) {
          if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            results.innerHTML += '<li>'+ status + '</li>';
          } else {
            results.innerHTML += '<li>' + result.name + '</li>';
          }
    });
}
```

(or add an alert if you don't mind clicking on all the popup dialog boxes)